# Does stripe in Selle Italia saddles form a channel?

Tags: saddle

**NOTE** -- I am NOT asking about saddles with hole (cutout).

Some saddles from Selle Italia have very distinctive stripe, take for example Selle Italia SL:

[image]

**The question is** -- does such stripe form some kind of channel? I.e. is the area softer (here it is denoted by black) than the rest of the saddle (here in white)? Or maybe it is embedded (the surface is lower than the rest of the saddle)?

Comment: Is there any information on the manufacturer's site about that?

Comment: @heltonbiker, what happened to "did you google it"?

Comment: Well, I asked first... (no offense!). What did YOU got from the manufacturer's site?

Comment: http://www.selleitalia.com/se_it3/prodotti/road/pagina_sl/

Comment: I would assume that since they make a saddle with a groove, that this saddle is pretty much the same density all over. The only real way to know will be to poke one-talk to your LBS.

Comment: @WTHarper, the problem is LBSs around me have very generic saddles, by their standards even SL is expensive saddle. In short -- all I can do is ask on the internet, maybe some owner will notice this question. I found out the picture of this saddle taken from the bottom, there is small patch visible which is very promising. It might be nothing, it might be an alternative to cutout -- and thus I am asking.

Comment: Most bike shops can get components from their distributors which you're not obligated to buy. Definitely ask, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, no. The leather/lorica/covering has no bearing on the shape of the saddle. They make a lot of versions of each design specifically for bike manufacturers with custom designed coverings in addition to their standard covering design.

They make quite a few saddles with grooves, without grooves, with and without cutouts. It's not entirely clear which model this is from your image or description as they do not have an "SL" model on their current product listing. They do have an "SLR" line and the shape appears to be of the "SLR monolink" variety which has both a non groove and groove model within it.

As stated above in the comments, it's best to go to your local shop and ask that if they do not have the item in stock, that they order one for you. Most will oblige because they can send items back if they are in unused condition. Some will ask for a deposit as a "holding" fee to ensure that you don't ask them to order a bunch of stuff and never come back.

Comment: Thank you, but in one regard you are mistaken -- Selle Italia has SL line in their current offering, hard to miss... INSANE :-D. When I was writing this post, SL line was on the main page, when I tried to answer you (~1 day difference), it is gone. They changed the offering meanwhile obviously -- new SLS is present, and quit old Q-Bik is back (good, it has channel).